# About iterations in Load Runner

Tags: load, runner

How could we use iterations in controller i.e. While running scenarios in controller?
How the iterations would be handled?

Please explain me.

Answer (score 3):

The key point here is to setup proper intervals for each script, so that required number of iterations can be achieved without compromising with concurrency.

Answer (score 2):

You should set up VUser count for each script before run the scenario. For do this use the radio Button "Basic Schedule" as run mode. This enables you to configure the number of virtual users per script. Also you can setup another option for running - you can tell, how many users run simultaneously and through what intervals increase their number.